# Can a state matrix have a row of zeros?

Tags: control, design, dynamics, self-driving

While formulating a state matrix of a system, say a system of a typical cruise controller,
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{v}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{b}{m} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{m} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
If we consider $b = 0$ (negligible), then does this state space matrix make sense any more and is it viable? A state matrix without state variable influence in equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a state matrix with zero rows and/or columns makes sense and is viable.  It typically signify pure integrators in the system.  In the example you give, 
$$
\dot{v} = -\frac{b}{m} v +\frac{1}{m} u
$$
where $v$ is the speed, $u$ is the externally applied force, and $bv$ is some viscous damping force. Now if the viscous damping coefficient is zero (no retarding force acting on the object of mass $m$, the differential equation becomes 
$$
\dot{v} = \frac{1}{m} u
$$
The $\dot{v}$ is integrated kinematically to obtain $v$, and your state-space model becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
[\dot{v}] &=& [0][v] + [1/m][u] \\ 
y &=& [1][v]
\end{eqnarray*}

Another way to look at it is to obtain the transfer function from $u$ to $y$ (the transfer function of the plant which you want to control), which becomes
$$
\frac{Y}{U} = \frac{1}{m}\cdot\frac{1}{s+b/m}
$$
which is a constant term ($1/m$) times a first-order lag.  For $b=0$, the transfer function becomes
$$
\frac{Y}{U} = \frac{1}{m}\cdot\frac{1}{s}
$$
which is simply a constant term ($1/m$) times an integrator ($1/s$).

### Edit: Controllability of the System

If the externally applied force is zero (i.e., $u=0$) the output of the integrator ($v$) remains constant; if $u>0$, the resulting acceleration ($\dot{v}=u/m$) is integrated "up" and the speed increases; if $u<0$, $\dot{v}$ is integrated "down" and the speed decreases.  Speed, of course, is the state variable in your system.  Thus, it is possible to transfer the system state from any initial state, $v(t_0)$, to any other state, $v(t_f)$, in a finite time by means of the input, *irrespective of the value of* $b$. So, by purely physical reasoning we can say thet the system is controllable.

Since this is a linear time-invariant system, the controllability matrix 
$$
\mathbf{Q} = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} & \cdots & \mathbf{A}^{n-1}\mathbf{B}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where $\mathbf{A}=[-b/m]$ is the state matrix, $\mathbf{B}=[1/m]$ is the input matrix, and $n=1$ is the number of state variables. For your system,
$$
\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{B} = \left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1/m
\end{array}
\right]
$$
i.e., a non-zero scalar which can be inverted (it is non-singular).  Thus, the rank of $\mathbf{Q}$ is one, and the system is controllable.

Comment: I am pretty clear now. Can you comment on the controllability of the system if $b = 0$? I found the rank of controllability matrix is **1**.

Comment: With pleasure, @AniketSharma.  I  have edited by answer to comment on that.